# CMake: access variable in defining scope from within a function

Tags: function, cmake, closures

I have created a project with a subproject in cmake. In the subproject I have a function which wants to access a variable from its defining scope (not the parent project scope).

This is my folder structure:

```
/project
|-- CMakeLists.txt
'-- /sub
    '-- CMakeLists.txt
```

Outer CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(mainproject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
add_subdirectory(sub)
message("in parent scope: ${V}")
test()
```

Inner CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(subproject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
set(V "hello")
message("defining scope: ${V}")

function(test)
    message("function scope: ${V}")
endfunction()
```

The output I get:

```
defining scope: hello
parent scope: 
function scope: 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

My suspicion would be that cmake simply doesn't support closures but then there is this page in the documentation:
[CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR.html#variable:CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR)

```
set(_THIS_MODULE_BASE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")

function(foo)
  configure_file(
    "${_THIS_MODULE_BASE_DIR}/some.template.in"
    some.output
  )
endfunction()
```

This is almost exactly my use case and exactly what I do but it doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Note that I could use `set(V "hello" PARENT_SCOPE)` but I don't want to pollute the parent scope.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "closure" semantic in CMake. Any variable's dereference uses the variable from the **current scope**. That is, if you call `test` function from the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, the variable `V` is searched in the scope of that script, not from the scope of `sub/CMakeLists.txt` which defines given function.

Only **special** variables like [CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR.html) or [CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION.html) are exception from that rule: they are expanded according to the place (file, line, function) where they are dereferenced.

The example of the code which confuses you

```
set(_THIS_MODULE_BASE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")

function(foo)
  configure_file(
    "${_THIS_MODULE_BASE_DIR}/some.template.in"
    some.output
  )
endfunction()
```

is for CMake **module** like `foo.cmake`.

Modules are included with **`include`** command:

```
include(foo)
...
foo()
```

which, unlike to `add_subdirectory`, does NOT introduce the scope (more info about variable's scoping is [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables)).
So variable `_THIS_MODULE_BASE_DIR` is **visible** to the caller of the function `foo`. (Would another module use the same variable name, then one variable would silently redefine another).

---

For make your code to work, you need to make `V` variable **visible to the caller** of your function. E.g you could set the variable with PARENT or CACHE option, or use global property instead of the variable.

Alternatively, you could move definition of the `test` function from `sub/CMakeLists.txt` to the module `test.cmake`, and include that module in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` via `include`.